# click a link/href and set a new link/href after click

Tags: javascript

I have a problem to do a command before the href link is set to a other one. I want to click on href link-one and do the command of link-one. After that the link should change to link-two. If link-two is pressed, do the command of link-two and change back to link-one.

With that function, i could switch on/off my light at home. At this time, i have two buttons for that, one for switching the light on and one for switching the light off.

Any help would be nice. Thanks.

***I found a solution to get it working. Maybe there are better ways to do it. To do the command of the link i had to add "target="_blank" in html.***

Javascript

```
function toggleclick() {    
var url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
var urltwo = new URL("http://www.example.com");
var link = document.getElementById("link");

if(link.href === url.href){
  document.getElementById("link").href = urltwo.href;
} 
  else if (url.href !== urltwo.href) {
    document.getElementById("link").href = url.href;
  } 
  console.log(link.href);
}
```

html

```
<div class="menubtn" id="3">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" id="link" onclick="toggleclick()" target="_blank">test</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a mistake in your if statements, because `link === link` and `link2 === link2` are always true. Maybe you wanted to do `link === 'link'` and `link2 === 'link2'`?

What’s the result of this?

Comment: that is only a showing example, but is not working. The only thing that works, is to set to 2Testlink/link2. But i want to do a click on link, do the command of link and then change link to link2. If link2 is clicked, do the command of link2 and change back to link. Don't know how to say it better.